# Construct a function which can form a Binary Search Tree recursively from an unsorted list/array of Integers

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I've been looking into for quite some time , but can't come up with a proper solution.

Sure we can sort a list of integers to form a BST with the help of a recursive function and call it a day, but there's just too many operations being performed.

I did create a simple function that forms a BST from an unsorted list of integers, but it isn't through **recursion**.

**class:**

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self,key):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.key = key
```

**function which displays the Tree**(rotated 90°)

```
def display_keys(node, space='\t', level=0):
    # print(node.key if node else None, level)
    
    # If the node is empty
    if node is None:
        print(space*level + '∅')
        return   
    
    # If the node is a leaf 
    if node.left is None and node.right is None:
        print(space*level + str(node.key))
        return
    
    # If the node has children
    display_keys(node.right, space, level+1)
    print(space*level + str(node.key))
    display_keys(node.left,space, level+1)
```

[Source for the display function](https://jovian.ai/learn/data-structures-and-algorithms-in-python/lesson/lesson-2-binary-search-trees-traversals-and-balancing)

**function which takes up a single element and adds it to the Tree**...

```
def gen_BST(node,key):
    if node is None:
        node = Tree(key)
    elif key < node.key:
        node.left = gen_BST(node.left,key)
    else:
        node.right = gen_BST(node.right,key)
    return node


int_list = [4,2,7,5,1,9,8,6,3]
tree = None
for val in int_list:
    tree = gen_BST(tree,val)
```

**Display:**

```
display_keys(tree)
```

So once again, is there any way to create a **recursive function** which to form a BST from an **unsorted** list of integers.

**Edit:**

The function should take up the entire list as an argument.

Comment: You already have it. `gen_BST` is recursive.

Comment: @trincot, I should've have rephrased my question a bit better, what I ment was the function should take up the entire list as an argument and then convert it to a BST, rather than taking a single element at a time